# Preg_match no matter what

Tags: php

I have been trying to match my one variable with the other. All I want that variable let's say `$word` contains no matter what in it matches with the the other variable lets say `$search_in` and echo results accordingly.

I have been using `if (preg_match("/$word/i", $search_in)) echo "matches";` but I am getting a lot of warnings like the following as I applied regexp on the values being returned from DB.

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '('
>
> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'T'

Comment: You can't just insert in $word as the regular expression, because if $word contains special characters it will be considered part of the regular expression and those special characters have special meaning there. They would need to be escaped. You should make sure these http://us3.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php are escaped as a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$word` most likely contains a slash in it.

You should use [`stripos`](http://php.net/stripos) for this, since you don't need the power of regular expressions at all:

```
if (stripos($search_in, $word) !== false) echo 'matches';
```

For the record, the `preg_match` way of doing it would be:

```
if (preg_match('/'.preg_quote($word, '/').'/i', $search_in)) echo 'matches';
```

Always prefer the string functions to regular expressions when the former can do the job.

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to check whether `$word` exists in `$search_in`, you can use:

```
if(stripos($search_in, $word) !== FALSE) echo "matches";
```

As the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) says:

> Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they will be faster.

Comment: Or `stripos` since the regex search was case insensitive.

Comment: `strpos` (or `stripos`) *never* returns `true`.

Comment: I want a match like "iphone" = "iphone5" means if there is iphone so echo "matches"

Comment: MichaelMior and netcoder: Very true. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: @softgenic This code will do what you need. It will match "iphone" within "iphone5".